# Hard drive not detected

Tags: hard-drive

Normally I am a Windows user and when my external hard drive crashed, I wanted to use the back up. Unfortunately this one was not detected and I could only find it in the Disk Manager. Here I was asked to initialize it which would mean a loss of the data. It was suggested that using Ubuntu might be a solution. So I installed Version 22.04.2 on another laptop. Here it is found when I use gnome-disk but not under lsblk. Is there any chance to save my data without having to use professional help?

Comment: I guess your backup is not a "backup". How do you create the backup?

Comment: Windows normally turns fast startup on for all NTFS partitions. That sets hibernation flag & prevents the Linux NTFS driver from normally mounting. You may be able to manually mount read only, if you create a mount point first. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using, as that will help in diagnosing your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility in the Ubuntu repositories called TestDisk. Credits to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223869/accidentally-formated-external-hard-drive?rq=1).

Here is an overview:

```
TestDisk checks the partition and boot sectors of your disks.
```

It is very useful in forensics, recovering lost partitions.
It works with :

- DOS/Windows FAT12, FAT16 and FAT32
- NTFS ( Windows NT/2K/XP )
- Linux Ext2 and Ext3
- BeFS ( BeOS )
- BSD disklabel ( FreeBSD/OpenBSD/NetBSD )
- CramFS (Compressed File System)
- HFS and HFS+, Hierarchical File System
- JFS, IBM's Journaled File System
- Linux Raid
- Linux Swap (versions 1 and 2)
- LVM and LVM2, Linux Logical Volume Manager
- Netware NSS
- ReiserFS 3.5 and 3.6
- Sun Solaris i386 disklabel
- UFS and UFS2 (Sun/BSD/...)
- XFS, SGI's Journaled File System

To install it run the following commands in a terminal:
`sudo apt update` followed by
`sudo apt install testdisk`

The documentation can be found [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf)

It can also recover various files such as photos etc using the PhotoRec facility which is included, please consult the documentation.

There are more versions (Windows, Mac, Arch etc) to download [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download).